# Custom receiver which works just like the default receiver

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I need to create a custom receiver for my app so I can add some tiny amount of javascript, except for that I want it to work just like the default receiver as that is what I am using today and I don't want to change my code much. Is there a sample out there which basically just does the exact same thing as the default Chromecast receiver?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The source for Default/Styled receivers is not open.

Comment: Is there an example designed to work with the CCL out of the box?

Comment: CCL is designed to work with Media Manager (cast.receiver.MediaManager) so as long as a receiver is using that, it should work.